# Controlling for White Matter when looking at a sub-section of White Matter in the Brain - Valid Statistically?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, ancova

I am interested in other people's opinion on the following matter.

I have just come across a brain imaging paper that looks at differences in the volume a sub-section of white matter (SS) in the brain.  The author's note that, when they control for white matter (WM) differences between groups, the differences in the SS is no longer significant.  However, I am just wondering how interesting this is.  It appears to me that co-varying for WM is just removing the group differences in SS, as WM and SS are likely similar constructs and are highly interrelated.

The authors point out that there are no significant differences in total white matter between disease and control groups in the study.  However, there is a mean reduction in the disease group.  There is also substantial evidence of white matter reductions in other studies.

I was just wondering what other people's thoughts were on this.  My apologies if it isn't worded in the best way.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the paper?